# “Je crois que tu devrais” or “je crois que tu doives”?

Tags: subjonctif, mode-grammatical

I recently learned the subjunctive and let's say I want to recommend something to someone and I want to say something along the lines of

> I think you should try...

I think the right way should be

> Je crois que tu devrais

but I think it might take the subjunctive since I'm expressing a desire or a wish...thanks

Comment: In your example, you do not express a desire but an opinion (croire, penser, etc.). To express a desire, you would use verbs like (vouloir, souhaiter, etc.).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Je crois que tu devrais faire comme ça.
>   Je crois que tu devrais prendre des vacances.
>   Je crois que tu devrais aller le voir.

are totally correct

> Je crois que tu doives

is not french at all

Comment: i just got it from the subjonctive conjugation http://www.wordreference.com/conj/FrVerbs.aspx?v=devoir

Comment: "que tu doives" can be used like so : "Je ne crois pas que tu doives prendre ces médicaments pour pouvoir dormir."

Comment: To be clear, the use of the indicative or subjunctive depends on the verb, i.e. if it's a verb that denotes opinion (croire, penser etc.) then you have to use indicative, however a verb that denotes consideration that has not yet happened (vouloir, souhaiter etc.) requires the use the subjunctive. I invite you to read this link : http://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-93819.php

Comment: @MorganFR but remember too, the 'opinion' verbs often **require** subjunctive when in the negative

Comment: thanks! i'm not a fan of all these rules but i'll get over it

Comment: @costrom Yes, I did mention the negative form in my first comment.